# P( X < 3 | X +Y) and E(X | min(X,t) ) X,Y iid exponetia(1) t > 0

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X, Y$ be i.i.d exponential random variables with $\lambda = 1 $and $t$ is some positive constant??

How to find the random variables:

a) $P(X < 3\mid X+Y) $

b) $E(X \mid \min(X,t))$

So far my attempts are:

a) let $K > 3$
$P(X < 3 \mid X + Y) =  P(X < 3\mid X + Y \leq k) $

$= P( [X < 3] \cap [X + Y \leq k ] )/P(X + Y \leq k)$

$= P( [X < 3] \cap [Y \leq k - 3] )/P(X + Y \leq k)$

$= P(X < 3) \cdot P(Y \leq k-3)/P(X + Y \leq k)$ by independence

b)
since the RV $\min(X,t) = X$ if $X < t$ and $t$ if $X \geq t$

so if $X < t$

$E(X \mid \min(X,t)) = E(X \mid X) = X$

if $X \geq t$

$E(X \mid \min(X,t)) = E(X \mid t) = E(X \mid X \geq t) = t+1$

and the problem I have with this is that I can't verify the this expression of 
$E(X | \min(X,t))$ satisfies the definition of conditional expectation

i.e $E(X I_A) = E(E(X \mid \min(X,t)) I_A)$ for all A in $σ(\min(X,t))$

Comment: please use latex for future question. clik on the edit button to see the code for mathy stuff. The math code goes between dollars signs ;)

Comment: @user4140: You might want to edit those $\leftarrow$'s to $\leq$, and $n$'s to $\cap$.

Comment: i wanted to edit but what the hell are the arrows?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part I don't see why $P(X<3\mid X+Y) = P(X<3\mid X+Y\leq k)$?

Clearly $P(X<3\mid X+Y)=0$ if $X+Y<3$.

For first part, I consider change of variable. Let $Z=X+Y$.

$f(x,y) = e^{-(x+y)}\mathbb{1}_{\{x>0,y>0\}}$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$. Then doing a change of variable. $z = x+y, x = x$, we have

$g(x,z) = e^{-z}\mathbb{1}_{\{z>0,x<z\}}$

Conditional on $z$, $g(x\mid z) = g(x,z)/g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is the density of $g$.

$g(z) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-z}\mathbb{1}_{\{z>0,x<z\}}\text{d}x = \int^z_0 e^{-z}\mathbb{1}_{\{z>0\}} \text{d}x= ze^{-z}\mathbb{1}_{\{z>0\}}$ i.e. $Z$ is a $\Gamma(2,1)$ distribution.

Now $g(x\mid z)= 1/z \mathbb{1}_{\{x<z\}}$, i.e. $X\mid Z$ is a uniform distribution $U(0,Z)$, so the answer to your question is

$3/X+Y$ if $X+Y>3$, $1$ otherwise.

For part 2

$E(X\mid\min(X,t)) = E(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X<t\}}\mid\min(X,t))+E(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X\geq t\}}\mid\min(X,t))= X{1}_{\{X<t\}}+E(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X\geq t\}}\mid X>t) $

The second bit calculate to $\dfrac{\int^\infty_t e^{-s}s \,\text{d}s}{\int^\infty_te^{-s}\,\text{d}s}$

PS I am not sure if this is just $1+t$, I think you are right. For any event $A$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(\min(X,t))$, write $A$ as $(A\cap\{X\geq t\}) \cup (A\cap\{X<t\})$. Take it from there.

Comment: Yea that integral is t+ 1, it's one of the characteristics of exponential RV. And yes I finally figured out how to check the second requirement of conditional expectation, it was because the way I defined the RV makes it not trivial/clear as to how to evaluate the integral. THank you very much!

Comment: +1. But replace "0 otherwise" by "1 otherwise".

Comment: huh?? what tick??

Comment: @AaronSitu there is a tick at the top of the question on the left hand side.